# Adding a textbox C#

Tags: c#

In **Program.cs** i added:

```
public void displayControls()
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Text = "Enter";
    tb.Location = new Point(300, 300);
    tb.Size = new Size(300, 300);
    tb.Visible = true;
    tb.Show();
    tb.BringToFront();
}
```

then in:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     this.displayControls();
}
```

But this is not working. Do i need to access form instance from **Form.cs** and add to that instance? What do i need to make that textbox visible in form?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do, programmatically create a textbox during run time to change the appearance of a form?

Comment: This codes has more errors than lines of code...

Comment: for me it seems you are trying to pop up a textbox in a console app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you are targeting WinForm application. You need to do that in your `Form.cs`, You can do that in `Form_Load` event like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Text = "Enter";
    tb.Location = new Point(300, 300);
    tb.Size = new Size(300, 300);
    tb.Visible = true;
    this.Controls.Add(tb); //here add it to the current form instance
}
```

Comment: How to call this function?

Comment: `Form1_Load`  will be called automatically as soon as your Form loads.

Comment: @Harikrishnan, you don't have to call that function, you need to make sure that your Form has an event `Form_Load`, simplest way would be to double click the Form in designer, that will attach a `Form_Load` event to your form. There you can have the lines like in answer or extract them to a function and call that from `Form_Load`, **just make sure**  to do `this.Controls.Add(tb);`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now i am understanding how the flow of control goes.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to put the UI related elements in the **Forms.cs**. It's easier and it has a better design.

You shouf check that if you Right Click the Form1.cs element on your Visual Studio Solution, you can access the "View Code" option. From here you can see the code related to the UI.

You will see this simple class definition

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

However, when you check the InitializeComponent method, you can see the instructions that will make the textbox appear. Be careful in not writing code in Form1.Designer.cs since it autogenerates the code each time you build

Answer (score 0):

`displayControls` should be a method of the *form*, not the *program*.  In addition you will need:

```
this.Controls.Add(tb);
```

to ensure it gets disposed of properly